# Elixir update nested keyword list

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to update a nested keyword list in elixir?
For example i am trying to make the following work

```
Keyword.put(conn.private.phoenix_endpoint.config(:url), :host, conn.host)
```

But somehow, the updated host is not reflected in the `conn` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Kernel.put_in/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3) which will work with a combination of maps and keyword lists.

```
put_in(conn, [:private, :phoenix_endpoint, :config, :url, :host], conn.host)
```

**Edit** As @manukall has pointed out, this won't work in this particular case as `conn.private.phoenix_endpoint` returns a module and not a map or a keyword list.

Comment: Thanks. Am getting the error `undefined function: Plug.Conn.get_and_update/3`. Do you know why that could be? Am i missing a library?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that, assuming you're in a phoenix app, `conn.private.phoenix_endpoint` will return your endpoint module. So you are basically calling `MyApp.Endpoint.config(:url)`. You can not change that functions return value in that way.

What you could probably do is overwrite the `phoenix_endpoint` key in `conn.private` to point it to some other module, but I don't think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Can you guide how to overwrite `phoenix_endpoint` ? Maybe i have to clone and change value?

Comment: It is best if you tell us which problem you are trying to solve because your current mindset of overwriting phoenix_endpoint or mutating an existing value simply is not going to work. :)